# FFMPEG for Windows - suggestions for how to overcome the " No such file or directory" issue

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG (Windows version)

I have files called 'MCR_0400.jpeg' numbered sequentially up to 'MCR_0450.jpeg'

When I run:
*ffmpeg -i 'MCR_%4d.jpeg' -start_number 0400 -c:v libx264 out.mp4*

it returns:
*Could find no file with path 'MCR_%4d.jpeg' and index in the range 0-4
'MCR_%4d.jpeg': No such file or directory*

I have spend the day trying all sorts of variations on the file name parameter: with and without quotes, full Windows path to it so I assume I'm doing something really stupidly wrong.

But I just cannot fathom it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Rename images to start at 0 rather than 0400

*ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i "MCR_%04d.jpeg" -c:v libx264 out.mp4*

is a solution